# Redirect to 404 is working but in chrome devtools, a 200 code is shown

Tags: iis, coldfusion, web-config, coldfusion-10

My web.config looks like this:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors>
            <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/error-404.cfm" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If I navigate to page that doesn't exist, it correctly loads up the 404 page, but chrome's network log shows a 200 response. How can I make sure there's a 404 response? Or does it matter?

Comment: Yes it does matter.  You want to send a 404 header back to the browser.  You can set that header in your ColdFusion template `/error-404.cfm`.  Just add this to that code `<cfheader statuscode="404" statustext="Not Found">`

Comment: Ahh okay. See I was using `<cfheader statuscode="404" statustext="Not Found">` in `onMissingTemplate`, and since it just redirected the user, the 404 code was never called.

Comment: For anyone running into a similar issue, this worked for me; put `<cffunction name="onMissingTemplate">  <cfinclude template="error-404.cfm" > </cffunction>` in the application.cfc file, then putting `<cfheader statuscode="404" statustext="Not Found">` at the top of error-404.cfm.

Comment: Patrick you should add your solution as an answer to the question. It is okay to answer your own question and it will make it more visible to others reaching this page.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone running into a similar issue, this worked for me; put

`<cffunction name="onMissingTemplate"> 
    <cfinclude template="error-404.cfm" > 
</cffunction>`

in the application.cfc file, then put

`<cfheader statuscode="404" statustext="Not Found">` at the top of error-404.cfm